# No way I can paint on my "donut project" - Texture paint issues

Tags: texture-painting, texture-paint-mode

I'm new to Blender, and I started with the donut tutorial. It was indeed quite easy until I got to the "texture paint" part.

I went on a lot of topics and tutorials to try to figure out what went wrong with what I did, but I never found out. Only, I guess, there is a lot of ways that things can go wrong.

Absolutely nothing happens when I try to paint nor on the left or the right side.

[image: screenshot]

[Drive link to my "Donut project"](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1dHSqURUMnG5DyF1z628JIr9s-fbTWT7u?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hello and welcome. You have better chances of getting a answers if all of the information 
is visible in this page, instead of asking users go through links 
just to understand what you want to do. Please use the [edit] link at 
the bottom of your post (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and use 
the tools from this site to upload images so that they are displayed 
as part of your question. See
[How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)

Comment: Your brush uses a texture but the texture is not set and empty. So the brush does not work. Remove the texture to fix it. [Click the X](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/brush/texture.html)

Answer (score 5):

### Your brush is using an empty Texture.

This is easy to fix:

Go to the panel on the right where all the brush settings are displayed.

[image: 1]

Scroll down to the *Texture* option and open it up.

[image: 2]

Click the X next to *Texture*.

[image: 3]

That should do it!

Comment: Wow thanks for the answers guys! That was it, I can keep on going now!

Comment: Happy to help out, @Darochaaable!

Comment: @Darochaaable if this answer solved your problem, make sure you hit the checkmark so everybody knows it's solved :)